# how to call a view from a controller in extjs mvc 4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-mvc

I have RowEdit in my view. I would like to able to call the controller so i can save the model.

My View

```
var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
    clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
    autoCancel: false,
    listeners: {
        afteredit: function () {
          // i want to call the controller from here
        }
    }
});

Ext.define('Pandora.view.MaterialsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.materialslist',
    store: 'Materials',
    title: 'Materials',
    plugins: [rowEditing]
}
```

I appreciate i may be going about this the wrong way and should be trying to catch this event in my controller but I have been unable to catch the event in my controller.

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs, the event you want is `edit` not `afteredit`. Try listening to that in your controller.

In case you still want to be able to do what you've asked:

In one of your controllers, in the init code, you will need to assign the application to a global variable. `APP = this.application`

Then, anywhere in your application, you can say `APP.getController('myController').myMethod()`